# Basic PHP input output

Tags: php, html, css

I'm new to php so i'm stuck with this basic problem. Here I created one textbox and one submit button. What I wanted is that when I type for instances the word "red" in the textbox it's background will automatically change into red but unfortunately the problem is that it's not taking any effect. Any help out there are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>

practice

</title>
<style type="text/css">
.red
{
background-color: red;
}
.blue
{
background-color: blue;
}
.yellow
{
background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$fval = $_POST["val"];
    if( isset( $_POST["colorme"] ) ) {
    if($fval == "red")
    {
    echo S_POST['val'] = "red";
    }
    elseif($fval == "blue")
    {
    echo  S_POST['val'] = "blue";
    }
    elseif($fval == "yellow")
    {
    echo S_POST['val'] = "yellow";
    }
    }

?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="val"  class="<?php echo $_POST['val'] ?>">

<input type="submit" name="colorme">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If by "when I type for instances the word "red" in the textbox it's background will automatically change into red. " you mean right that instant, you would need to use javascript. 

Otherwise, please explain what the actual problem is. You haven't asked a question, you've just said what you want to do.

Comment: you need to do some javascript here to change the colour to red

Comment: You don't need at all to call your server side code to perform this process David.

Comment: `<red>` is not a valid html tag. Since it's invalid, your browser will simply skip over/ignore it.

Comment: i've edited my codes sorry for not being clear enough.,

Answer (score 1):

Your Example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>practice</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     .red{background-color: red;}
     .blue{background-color: blue;}
     .yellow{background-color: yellow;}
    </style>
   </head>
<body>
 <?php
    $fval = isset($_POST["val"])?trim($_POST["val"]):'';   
 ?>
 <form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="val"  class="<?php echo $fval ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="colormoko">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: next step to learn php ... switch $fval for valid "inputs" ... take a look on php switch()

Comment: i tried your code but the background color is not changing. by the way i'm using xampp, and I something must be wrong with it instead of the code.

Comment: @DavidDiaz works perfekt in FF (Browser) .. to test the input/output add this line in body **<div style="width:50px; height:30px; border:1px solid black;" class="<?php echo $fval?>"></div>**

Comment: when you said FF do you mean firefox?. I'm using that already and i've added the <div> tag but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this for me its working

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        practice

    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .red
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .blue
        {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .yellow
        {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$fval = "";
if( isset( $_POST["colormoko"] ) ) {
    $fval = $_POST['val'];
    if($fval == "red")
    {
        echo "<red>";
    }
    elseif($fval == "blue")
    {
        echo"<blue>";
    }
    elseif($fval == "yellow")
    {
        echo"<yellow>";
    }
}

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="val"  class="<?php echo $fval ?>">

    <input type="submit" name="colormoko">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: that's no valid html at all!

Comment: @ElefantPhace just tested this and it works.

Comment: That is not valid HTML, however many browsers will try to be smart about invalid HTML and make it work. I have not tried this specific example but I have seen FF work with block tags that are just made up out of thin air as long as it described in a stylesheet. That said, you should stick with valid HTML and not rely on what a browser might do to figure things out on its own.

Comment: Still not sure why you're echoing <red> and the like

Comment: @new guy, those tags aren't doing anything. He is setting the class of the textbox upon submit

Comment: @AnandPatel the output of this example will be **class="<red>"** and that is not valid!

Comment: @donald no it isn't! He never sets $fval to <red> its just red he is only unnecessarily echoing those because they were in the OP

Comment: @ElefantPhace you are right ;)

Comment: actually i think it's true that it's almost like i'm issuing a class="<red>" instead of class="red". by the way Anand, how did you make it run? It's not working for me, I'm using xampp btw.

Comment: what i have seen in view source is class="blue" not class="<blue>"

Comment: @AnandPatel how did you make my code works. It appears that you just remove the $_POST['val'] and leave it as "". I tried that but still not working. I'm using xampp by the way.

Comment: what procedure you follow ? what i do i enter blue in textbox and click on submit

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeColor() {
  var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox_coloring");
  var color = textBox.value;
  textBox.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> coloring textbox </title>
    <meta charset = 'utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type = 'text' id = 'textbox_coloring' onkeyup='changeColor();'/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This snippet change the color of the textBox by altering the style of the textBox by inserting the text value. 
It use the "onkeyup" javascript property which permit to access the textBox after a key is pressed.

Comment: thanks for trying but unfortunately you don't have a submit button puls i'm focusing for php for the time being.